# find environment in makefile on windows

Tags: makefile

How can I check in a makefile if I am running in a posix shell (`msys`/`cygwin`) or the windows `cmd` shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
ifeq ($(shell echo %OS%),%OS%)
$(info Running in a POSIX shell)
else
$(info Running in a Windows cmd shell)
endif
```

You could replace `%OS%` with any standard environment variable defined in a DOS environment.